# Can't immediately import a module installed on script when using the pip --prefix option

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```
import subprocess
import sys

sys.path.append("/home/user/python_install/lib/python3.6/site-packages")

try:
  from pytz import reference
except:
  subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 'pytz', "--prefix=python_install"])
  from pytz import reference
```

In the above code snippet, if initial import fails I want to install the module in a local folder and retry the import.

The issue that I'm facing is that the import (after installation) is not working in the 1st run of the script:

```
Installing collected packages: pytz
Successfully installed pytz-2021.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timezone_test2.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pytz import reference
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timezone_test2.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pytz import reference
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
```

On the next runs of the script the module is imported without any issue.
Already validated that `sys.path` is correct, and `pip` installs the module in the right place.

If I remove `"--prefix=python_install"` to use instead the default directory, the same strategy works at 1st (even if module is not installed).

Also if I try `pip3 install --prefix="/home/user/python_install" pytz` and then run the script, it is capable of import the module at first run without issues.